I can't cancel/delete events via graph API (application permissions)
I have registered an app in Azure with application permissions (BookingsAppointment.ReadWrite.All). When I try to cancel an appointment, I get an Internal server error. I use Logic apps. Can you tell me where I have a problem?
I tried to find more in the documentation, and I found that I have to add Bookings.ReadWrite.All permission to app, but this option is not available for the application:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/bookingappointment-cancel?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I have this same issue.
